# jQuery ajax tooltips: where to find a nice plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I saw one perfect ajax tooltip at forum engine [Xenforo](http://xenforo.com/community/forums/announcements/) (try mouseover on any topic and you'll see).

I know it's made with jQuery.

Maybe there are some nice plugins in internet like this.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use qTip2 http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ and I'm really happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

Tooltips are now part of **jQuery UI** (Since version 1.9)

Have a look at the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) and the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Comment: but can you put object in it? like div with image + table

Comment: @T.G: Yes, it's possible, even dynamic content. You have to use the `content` property.

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting their code tells that they load the [Flowplayer tooltip plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html).

You can override the `.tooltip` in your own css and customize the tooltip look. You can also  customize how it animate as you like following their [documentation](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/custom-effect.html).

Comment: I'm not sure. Similar, but not that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend you [this one](http://www.ionden.com/widgets/wg/popcom/). It's very simple and light solution.

Comment: спасибо! неплохие подсказки, но я нашел бета версию jquery ui 1.9 tooltip http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/tooltip/default.html - как раз то, что я искал. Она хоть и сыровата, но вполне сойдет, и релиз как я понял уже скоро будет...

Comment: @Vitali Ponomar я тоже давно за ними слежу, мб переведу свои проекты на них